# How do I install linux or ubuntu 13.04 alongside windows 7 without the option?

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, linux-mint

I'm booting linux mint 15 off an 8gb pendrive. I'm trying to install linux mint, but it only says "replace windows 7" and "something else". does anyone know how I can install it without removing windows 7?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the drive partitioned.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

select the drive `/dev/sd(something)` you want to install install linux in. double click it. get a calculator and do 50, 60 or 75 multiplied by 1024. now, subtract that from the number in the textbox in the top and type down the answer in the textbox.Click OK.

in the free space created, double-click it. make sure the type is logical. this will be the case for all the steps from now. now, depending on how much space you want, do 15, 20 or 25 multiplied by 1024. location will ***ALWAYS*** be beginning, us as will ***mostly*** be ext4 journaling file system. now in the mount point, just select the slash. now click OK.

in the free space, double click. in the textbox(size) type 512. the mount point must be `/boot`. the type is logical and the "use as" is the same as last time. click OK.

next, in the free space, type the amount of RAM that your computer has multiplied by 1024 in the textbox. the type is logical. the "use as" **must** be swap area. click OK.

next, (the last step) in the free space, double-click. ***the "using as" is on ext4 journaling file system again.*** in the drop down menu, it is `/home`. leave the rest as it is. click OK.

now you can go onto the next step. After installing, reboot. you will get a "grub" menu. you can select windows 7 (loader) and your distro of linux. leave the rest alone. now, at boot, you can choose where to boot from.
enjoy your linux!